# How do I get this List in diagonally sorted order in Java

Tags: java, sorting, diagonal

I just want to ask how will I be able to achieve getting a list of data in a 2D Table? Table is in (row,col,data) order...

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CdFi.png)
So if you were going to arrange the data inside that table in a diagonally order, you'll get something like **[(4,1,B),(4,2,B),(5,3,A),(1,1,A),(2,2,B),(2,3,A),(2,4,B),(1,5,A)]** inside the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the lower left cell is **(0,0)**, and the upper right cell is **(n,n)**. Then the sum of the two indexes of a cell gives you the number of the diagonal as needed for the ordering.

If two cells are on the same diagonal, then the one with lower column index should go first.

Finally, because row index increases from top to bottom, you should negate the row index when using it.

That would be:

```
int aDiag = a.getCol() - a.getRow();
int bDiag = b.getCol() - b.getRow();
return aDiag != bDiag ? aDiag - bDiag : a.getCol() - b.getCol();
```

That is - if the diagonals are different, use just the diagonals. If they are equal, use the column indexes.

Comment: Yeah why I didn't think about that! Thanks